# Paypal Rest api: How to delete a billing plan?

Tags: paypal

The paypal developer documentation explains the steps to create and activate a [Billing plan](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/).

Is there a way to delete a billing plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to ***DELETE*** a Billing Plan.

If you see the samples in the [REST-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK), there is a file named [DeletePlan.php](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/billing/DeletePlan.php) which has the code to delete the billing plan.

It goes something like this:

```
$createdPlan = require 'CreatePlan.php';

use PayPal\Api\Plan;

try {
    $result = $createdPlan->delete($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    ResultPrinter::printError("Deleted a Plan", "Plan", $createdPlan->getId(), null, $ex);
    exit(1);
}

ResultPrinter::printResult("Deleted a Plan", "Plan", $createdPlan->getId(), null, null);

return $createdPlan;
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 18):

An alternative way of deleting a **BillingPlan** (as per the original question) is to submit a patch request. Unfortunately this isn't too clear from looking at the API docs: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/#plan_update

You want to patch the *state* of the BillingPlan into *DELETED*:

```
[
    {
        "path": "/",
        "value": {
            "state": "DELETED"
        },
        "op": "replace"
    }
]
```

Once patched, the deleted plan no longer shows up when you list all available plans via */v1/payments/billing-plans*

Comment: This does not work on the new API  `/v1/billing/plans/' + id`.  PP says `/v1/payments` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @smiling_warrior.

For the python API https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_agreements/replace.py

I used:

```
a=paypalrestsdk.BillingPlan.find("P-98072754CC611563JLOGIIYA")
a.replace([{"op": "replace","path": "/","value": {"state":"DELETED"}}])
```

Or delete all:

```
allplans = paypalrestsdk.BillingPlan.all()
for plan in allplans.plans:
    a=paypalrestsdk.BillingPlan.find(plan.id)
    a.replace([{"op": "replace","path": "/","value": {"state":"DELETED"}}])
```

Comment: The Python SDK uses the endpoint `/v1/payments/billing-plans` which is now deprecated so it no longer works for this. You should instead use the REST API endpoint `/v1/billing/plans`.

Answer (score 2):

As a complementary information about [@maxxon15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29670037/330867) answer, here's the [actual code](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/b2c244199bfffa5f99178acdd1b463a14c398d63/lib/PayPal/Api/Plan.php#L399) that does the **DELETE** on the PHP SDK :

```
public function delete($apiContext = null, $restCall = null)
{
    ArgumentValidator::validate($this->getId(), "Id");
    $patchRequest = new PatchRequest();
    $patch = new Patch();
    $value = new PayPalModel('{
        "state":"DELETED"
    }');
    $patch->setOp('replace')
        ->setPath('/')
        ->setValue($value);
    $patchRequest->addPatch($patch);
    return $this->update($patchRequest, $apiContext, $restCall);
}
```

So in other terms, it simply does an update (**PATCH**) to the billing endpoint, as stated by [@smiling-warrior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311311/330867)

```
[
    {
        "path": "/",
        "value": {
            "state": "DELETED"
        },
        "op": "replace"
    }
]
```